# URLs getting truncated in QuarkXpress running on macOS Mojave

Tags: mojave, quarkxpress

I've just noticed a problem with [QuarkXPress](http://www.quark.com/Products/QuarkXPress/) that may or may not be related to macOS Mojave.

Sometimes when I add a new hyperlink or edit an existing one, the full URL path is being truncated and this breaks the link.

Has anyone else experiencing the same? If yes, did they manage to fix it?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) This may seem a little strange of me, but can you please confirm that you're talking about QXP 2018 and **not** an earlier version (say 2017)?

Comment: @Monomeeth Well this is embarrassing. I have the trial version of QuarkXPress 2018 installed, but it was QuarkXPress 2017 I originally designed the file in. I just download the trial on another Mac (it had expire on this one) and editing the hyprlinks worked to fix the problem. I will go to Quark as they should fix the problem in QuarkXPress 2017 rather than force me to buy new version. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until recently this was actually a known problem in QuarkXPress (and I may add still is for a lot of other software that deals with URLs). Basically, the issue is that the maximum character length of the URL field in the New/Edit
Hyperlink box is 250 characters and, as a result, longer links were truncated. This issue is unrelated to macOS.

However, this issue was resolved when QuarkXpress 2018 was released in May 2018. I *believe* the issue still exists in QXP 2017 and earlier and, if so, you’d have to upgrade to QXP 2018.

If in fact you’re using QXP 2018, your best bet would be to check for any updates (you can do this via the Quark Update preference pane in **Apple > System Preferences**). If you’re using QuarkXpress 2018 Pro (the version sold on the Mac App Store), then you’ll need to check via the App Store for any updates.

However, my understanding is that this issue was resolved with release 14.0 (which was the first public release of QXP 2018 in May). See [QuarkXPress 2018 Known and Resolved Issues](http://files.quark.com/download/documentation/QuarkXPress/2018/english/QXP-2018-December-Update-Known-and-Resolved-Issues-EN.pdf).

If the issue still persists you’d be best to contact [Quark Technical Support](http://www.quark.com/Support/) and/or visit their [online forums](https://forums.quark.com).